# Is my Laravel api safe even if I don't use Sanctum or Passport

Tags: laravel

My plan is to import a CSV and create users based on the information in the CSV. During this process, I want
to generate an access token for every user, which I can later display in a QR code. The QR code will be scanned to import the API URL and the access token to the App.

My problem is that I’ve created a controller that generates a random string and saves it into the `api_token` column as described in [this guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication) from Laravel. The authentication works fine, and everything seems to be okay, but I’m not sure if it’s safe to use this publicly. Do you have any recommendations on how I can verify if my API data is adequately protected? I’m always a bit uncertain about the security of my APIs and applications.

Controller store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'Key1' => 'required', #etc
        ]);

        return betreuer::create([

            'Key1' => $request["Key1"], #etc
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);
    }
```

In the *config/auth.php*

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [  #added api 
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 't_betreuer',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        't_betreuer' => [  #added custom model and table
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\betreuer::class,
        ],

      ],
```

Example for protected route in api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::resource('betreuer', controller_betreuer::class);
    });
```

Comment: Of course Passport & Sanctum are reliable but you  have also to add more security like double checking authenticated user and the permissions. (The world of Internet nothing is safe) but do what you can do and if someday you find a leak you fix it. This is how it goes :D

Comment: You are just simply using a bearer/token based authentication. Very plainly said locking the session with a limited token. Just scan all the relevant pages on any search engine to find out if any of the weak spots with this method reflects to your application. Till then, it works until something goes wrong ;)